# Use count function with IIF in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to count a field based on the date in another field. s there a way to perform this function in SSRS?

I have tried
`=CountDistinct(IIF(IsDate(Fields!EntrySystemDate.Value)=IsDate("d",-1,Today()),1,0) AND ((Fields!DesignCode.Value),1,0)`

Comment: Two questions, which will help refine the answer already given. `1.` Are you trying to say "Count distinct DesignCode values for yesterdays records" and `2.` Is EntrySystemDate a Date, DateTime or other datatype ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is with `IsDate`, it's a true/false function. You'll need to use `DateAdd`. I'm not sure how you want to evaluate `DesignCode`.

`=CountDistinct(IIF(FormatDateTime(Fields!EntrySystemDate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate) = FormatDateTime(DateAdd("d",-1,Today()),1,0), DateFormat.ShortDate) AND ((Fields!DesignCode.Value),1,0)`